# How create auto click function on a bootstrap nav (like carousel)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap nav like that (without disabled tab) on my home page :

[bootstrap nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz4qc.png)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tab_home" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#presentation" role="tab" aria-controls="presentation" aria-selected="true">Tab_1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#plat-sem" role="tab" aria-controls="plat-sem" aria-selected="false">Tab_2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#avis" role="tab" aria-controls="avis" aria-selected="false">Tab_3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a js effect (a bit like a carousel) by an automatic click on next tab every 5 seconds, that in loop. I'm sure it's not a difficult function but I've tried all this afternoon without success.

Something like that have good effect but just with the first (with the next 2 contents display in the same time, why ?) :

```
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("id_tab_2").click();
}, 5000);
```

I've also tried something like that without success :

```
function click_tabs(tab) {
    setInterval(function() {
        tab.click();
    }, 5000);

    // OR
    // tab.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //     setInterval(function() {
    //         tab.click();
    //     }, 5000);
    // })
}
document.querySelectorAll("#tab_home a").forEach((tab) => click_tabs(tab));
```

What do I have to do to have the good result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the below. Reset the `currentTab` to `first` if it exceeds the number of tabs on the page.

```
let currentTab = 0;
setInterval(() => {
   var tabs = document.querySelectorAll("#tab_home a");
   tabs[currentTab].click();
   currentTab++;
   
   if (currentTab >= tabs.length)
    currentTab = 0;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks @Sowmyadhar for this great answer, it works !

Answer (score 0):

You are clicking tab but not closing it. You can create a button or tab that does nothing. So,
(1) click TAB1
(2)then it should sleep for sometime
(3) click a nothing I'd tab or button
(4) CLICK TAB2
follow 2,3